# Laravel: Can I add custom method to API Controller that routed by api.php?

Tags: php, laravel

I know I can easily create API in laravel, like below.

**`Http/Controllers/Api/MyApiController.php`**

```php
use App\Model\MyModel;

class MyApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $models = MyModel::all();
        return $models;
    }

    ....
```

**`routes/api.php`**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function(){
    Route::resource('myTable', 'Api\MyApiController');
});
```

But it seems that it has only basic CRUD methods.
Is there a way to add custom method and call it by some Http requests?
I mean, If I added my own method like as follows:

```php
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $models = MyModel::all()->where('id', '>', 100)->get();
        return $models;
    }
```

I want to use it by such a request as `GET /api/MyMethod/{id}`.
Does anyone know any ways without adding route to `web.php`?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. You just need to define those routes in your `routes/api.php` file.

**`routes/api.php`**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function(){
    Route::resource('myTable', 'Api\MyApiController');

    // Define new routes like this
    Route::get('myTable/MyMethod/{id}', 'Api\MyApiController@myMethod');
});
```

---

**Update**

Even though its perfectly fine to define routes with custom method names (other than the basic CRUD ones) in such a way, it can often lead to overpopulated controllers. Check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI) interesting talk by Adam Wathan about this issue.

Comment: That worked! I didn't notice I should have write rooting path inside of Route::group(). thank you so much!